# asp.net: Why I cannot find pictures in my Temp Internet File folder when I view my own website?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website which displays a lot of photos, built with asp.net and sql server with the photos stored in a folder in the server and a pointer to photo stored in the sql server. I hosted the website on my Windows computer with iis7 and when I view the website from the same computer, I cannot find any photos in the Temp Internet Files folder. Not sure about using another computer as the website is not online yet. So what is happening here? Am I doing something wrong or IE does not download picture into temp folder from localhost??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do when I want to display images from another folder stored on the server.  I'm rather new, so what I'm doing might not be the most efficient or best way, but it works, and might give you an idea of how to change your code to get your desired result.

1) Add the path on the server to the web.config, under appSettings.

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientContactBusinessCardImagePath" value="C:\Content\BusinessCards\" />
    <add key="SupportLogPDFPath" value="C:\Content\SupportLogPDFs\" />
    <add key="NewsAttachmentPath" value="C:\Content\NewsAttachments\" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
     //etc.
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2) Here's my method to display a business card from a folder stored on the server, but isn't part of the project:

```
private void showBusinessCard(int setwidth)
{
    float fileWidth;
    float fileHeight;
    float sizeratio;
    float calculatedheight;
    int roundedheight;
    try
    {
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientContactBusinessCardImagePath"] + BusinessCardLabel.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fstream);
        fstream.Dispose();
        fileWidth = image.Width;
        fileHeight = image.Height;
        sizeratio = fileHeight / fileWidth;

        calculatedheight = setwidth * sizeratio;
        roundedheight = Convert.ToInt32(calculatedheight);

        imgbusinesscard.Width = setwidth;
        imgbusinesscard.Height = roundedheight;

        imgbusinesscard.ImageUrl = "ImageHandler.ashx?img=" + BusinessCardLabel.Text;
        hlbusinesscard.NavigateUrl = "ImageHandler.ashx?img=" + BusinessCardLabel.Text;
    }
    catch
    {
        imgbusinesscard.ImageUrl = "~/images/editcontact/businesscard-noimage.png";
        imgbusinesscard.Width = 240;
        imgbusinesscard.Height = 180;
    }
```

3) And the ImageHandler that is being called in the middle there, looks like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        string imageFileName = context.Request.QueryString["img"];

        System.Drawing.Image objImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(Path.Combine(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientContactBusinessCardImagePath"], imageFileName));

        if (imageFileName != null)
        {
            MemoryStream objMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            objImage.Save(objMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] imageContent = new byte[objMemoryStream.Length];
            objMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            objMemoryStream.Read(imageContent, 0, (int)objMemoryStream.Length);
            objMemoryStream.Dispose();
            objImage.Dispose();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageContent);
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Well, to be honest your question was kind of vague, but I figured rather than let the question sink into obscurity in the pile of unanswered questions, I'd provide you with working code that has yet to fail us, and maybe it would get you thinking about another direction on how to solve your problem.  Guess it didn't.